# If $T_1T_2 = T_2T_1$, why $r(T_1 + T_2) \leq r(T_1) + r(T_2)$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two bounded linear operators in a complex banach space $X$.

> If $T_1T_2 = T_2T_1$, I want to know how to show that 
>   $$
> r(T_1+T_2) \leq r(T_1) + r(T_2),
> $$
>   where $r(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$, and it is given by
>   $$
> r(A) = \inf_{n>0} \|A^n\|^{1/n} =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|A^n\|^{1/n}.
> $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321396/is-the-spectral-radius-subadditive

Comment: For the record, the proof is on p. 426 of Riesz and Szőkefalvi-Nagy "Functional Analysis" https://books.google.com/books?id=JCfEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA426&dq=Functional+analysis+riesz+nagy+for+permutable+S+and+T+we+have&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyyOr-3YPbAhWrq1kKHTi2AiIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Functional%20analysis%20riesz%20nagy%20for%20permutable%20S%20and%20T%20we%20have&f=false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simplicity, assume that $\|T\| \leqslant 1$ and $\|S\| \leqslant 1$. Write
$$ (T + S)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \tbinom{n}{k} T^k S^{n - k} . $$
Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $m$ be large enough, so that $\|T^j\| \le (r(T) + \varepsilon)^j$ and $\|S^j\| \le (r(S) + \varepsilon)^j$ for $j \ge m$. Then, if $n > 2 m$, we have
$$ \begin{aligned} \|(T + S)^n\| & \leqslant m \tbinom{n}{m} (\|T^{n - m}\| + \|S^{n - m}\|) + \sum_{k = m}^{n - m} \tbinom{n}{k} (r(T) + \varepsilon)^k (r(S) + \varepsilon)^{n - k} \\
&\leqslant m \tbinom{n}{m} ((r(T) + \varepsilon)^{n - m} + (r(S) + \varepsilon)^{n - m}) + (r(T) + r(S) + 2 \varepsilon)^n . \end{aligned} $$
Since $(m \tbinom{n}{m})^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, we easily find that
$$
r(T + S) \leqslant \max\{r(T) + \varepsilon, r(S) + \varepsilon, r(T) + r(S) + 2 \varepsilon\} = r(T) + r(S) + 2 \varepsilon .
$$
This gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Where exactely you have used the fact that $\|T\| \leqslant 1$ and $\|S\| \leqslant 1$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student: In the first inequality, to have $\|T^{n-k} S^k\| \le \|T\|^{n-k} \|S\|^k \le \|T\|^{n-m}$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, m - 1$.

Comment: Thank you. Please what about the general situation when $\|T\| \nleq 1$ and $\|S\| \nleq 1$? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Student: Then you simply apply the above estimate to $\lambda T$ and $\lambda S$ for an appropriately small $\lambda > 0$.